# Manga where main character has bbq with demons in one chapter

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I think the manga was about a reincarnated person that is taken in by a noblewoman. He is visited by a demon girl a few times. She is able to sneak into the mansion/castle and she eventually invites the MC to dinner.

He ends up going and it turns out to be a bbq with other demons in the forest. The demons are all “family” and has been taken in by the girl demon who was actually a high ranking and powerful demon. I think one of the demons was also a reincarnated person from the past.

I started it a few months ago but lost track of it and cannot remember the name. Couldn’t remember much more than the bbq chapter. Anyone have any idea which one this is?

Comment: https://tondemo-skill.fandom.com/wiki/Barbecue_%C3%97_Blessing_of_Gods

Comment: That one wasn’t it, it wasn’t a crossover, and I don’t think it has any tamed monsters. 

The MC was really powerful, and the I think he adventures with the humans he was staying with. The demon girl would break through the mansions barrier and met with the hero. They didn’t fight, and I think the humans even got invited to the demon girls place. 

It wasn’t about the bbq, that was just one of the things they did one chapter. Can’t remember the other details from the story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is *I Was Caught up in a Hero Summoning, but That World Is at Peace*.

The manga starts off with the main character being summoned and then meets a demon girl in a market. She then sneaks into the castle and takes him flying. When the others he was summoned with are invited to a dinner without him, the demon girl invites him to a BBQ. At the BBQ, he meets various demons and monsters. One, however, is a female knight who asks him about Japan. She then tells the main character she had been summoned from Japan in the past, refused to return, and reincarnated in this new world.

After the BBQ, the main character talks with some of the people who summoned him, and they think the demon girl would be at least the equivalent of a Count or Duke. A little while later, we find out the demon girl's title is "Dark King".

Comment: That’s it, thank you. It was driving me crazy looking for it.